# ¿Cómo manejar variables de entorno en docker?

Tags: nodejs, docker

Muy buenas, tengo un incoveniente con mis variables de entorno, necesito hacer un contenedor en docker en el cual quiero incluir mi proyecto (node js), pero no se como manejar las variables de entorno porque mi proyecto funciona local, pero al hacer el contenedor y probarlo no me fuiona.

Answer (score 5):

Hola en tu ***Dockerfile*** debes utilizar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
# Sin valor por defecto
ENV foo

# Con un valor por defecto
ENV bar /bardata
ENV PORT=3000

# Como utilizarlos durante el Build
ADD . $bar #ADD . /bardata
COPY . mydata${PORT} #COPY . /mydata3000
```

Si lo que quires es definirlo al ejecutar `docker run` tu código quedaría como sigue:

```sh
docker run -it -e "PORT=3000" -e "name=allexiusw" \ 
--name test_env busybox bash
```

Obtendrás bash donde podrás imprimir la variable de entorno desde el container como sigue:

```
echo $PORT
echo $name
```

Para utilizarlo desde Nodejs te comparto este ejemplo:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(),
      port = process.env.PORT || 3080;

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('App Works !!!');
});

app.get('/time', (req,res) => {
    res.send(new Date());
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on the port::${port}`);
});
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.